# Difference between 2 cubed prime numbers cubed being a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Recently, one of my particular friends, had decided to play around with primes. How annoying that would turn out...

Lets assume that we have 2 numbers, $p$ and $q$.

There is only one instance where $p$ and $q$ are all prime and...

> $p^3$ - $q^3$ = $a$ $prime$

What is $p$, $q$, and the difference bewteen the cubes of both?

**What seems clear to me**

The difference between the cubes has to be Odd. If it was even, then it would have to be 2, but there are no 2 cube numbers next to each other by 2 integers.

So we have determined the difference to be Odd. But what about $p$ and $q$?

It turns out that either it is:

> Odd - Even = Odd

or

> Even - Odd = Odd

and as odd$^3$ is always odd, and even$^3$ always even, this is also talking about $p$ and $q$.

$p$ cannot be even, as then $p$ = 2, and 8 - $q^3$ = a prime gives no solution for $q$.

Therefore, $q = 2$.

**What next?**

What next after determining $q = 2$? How would we find $p$ and the difference, apart from guess and check? I'm assuming it has to do with something about the last digit sums, or something along those lines. But for now, I'm stumped.

Comment: Since $p^2+pq+q^2>1$, this implies $p-q=1$ then putting $p=1+q$ solve $(q+1)^2+q(q+1)+q^2=a$ where, $p,q$ is a positive integer pair.

Comment: Why does it imply that $p-q = 1$?

Comment: $x^3-y^3$ is divisible by $x-y$.

Comment: All but one case of primes being the difference between two cubes are of @lonestudent's type and one of those is the difference of the cubes of two primes (small).  The only other case  of a prime being the difference between two cubes  is a counter-example to your statements "The difference between the cubes has to be Odd" and "there are no 2 cube numbers next to each other by 2 integers" and is even smaller though might require some imagination to spot.

Comment: @Stevo $$p^3-q^3=(p-q)(p^2+pq+q^2).$$

Answer (score 1):

I ama not sure if I understood your question right, but I am sure that $3^3-2^3=27-8=19$ is the only prime that you can get. That is due to the fact that $p^3-q^3$ divides $p-q$.

Hope it helped!